# Why does my program have this weird behavior?

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple controller:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.value = 1;

  $scope.getIncrementValue = function() {
    return $scope.value + 1;

  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<p>{{getIncrementValue()}}</p>
```

Which renders "2".

But as soon as I change to `return $scope.value += 1;` , I get some weird error and output in my browser is 23.

I could not find out why

Comment: And the weird error is...? Why would you want to obfuscate your code like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS analyzes your code and creates a structure of dependencies. Look at your first function that has `return $scope.value + 1;`. If anything would change the value of `$scope.value`, then this function would be executed again and the view would be updated.

Now look at `return $scope.value+=1;`. The function changes its own dependency, which means that it gets executed again, changes its own dependency, so its executed again, changes its own dependency... you get the picture.

AngularJS has a limit of such cycles, that's why it interrupts the process and the `$scope.value` is stuck at some arbitrary value.

Answer (score 6):

Calling stateful, state-altering functions in your view interpolation is a **very** bad idea. You have basically no specific control over *when* or *how often* this function will be called.

View refreshes are triggered by many things in angular, so your function most likely actually gets executed 22 times.

You can check that by adding a `console.log($scope.value)` in your function, to see in the console how often it runs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems OK - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ciRJtryjmijdrQSC3qoJ?p=preview)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 1;

    $scope.incrementValue = function()
    { 
         $scope.value += 1;
    };
});
```

Markup

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>{{value}}</p>
    <button ng-click="incrementValue()">Increment</button>
</body>
```

No need to return.

Answer (score 0):

Angular have Digest cycle that call any time and it verify any change in scope variables and It also call the functions you have bind.

Here are the steps as per you functionality.

1. First digest call function getIncrementValue().
2. getIncrementValue() change the value that is in scope.
3. Digest again called so updated value can update if that is using some other place also. AND HERE IT ALSO CHANGE THE VALUE.

So it is infinite loop.

See in the below example. I am updating another value and on every change your function also called :)

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/CVX2IXErS4hIT7fLfzBx?p=preview][1]
```